# "sudo apt-get purge mysql" Failing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'm pretty sure something went **seriously** wrong in my MySQL installation. I have tried pretty much all of the solutions at the following links:
[How to repair corrupt package installation (mysql)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773287/how-to-repair-corrupt-package-installation-mysql), [How to completely delete MySQL for clean install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735601/how-to-completely-delete-mysql-for-clean-install), [How do I uninstall MySQL completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely). But unfortunately, nothing has worked. When each of these solutions was tried, a common error was generated, which is as follows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient20 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04)
                    Breaks: libmysqlclient20:i386 (!= 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04) but 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
 libmysqlclient20:i386 : Depends: mysql-common:i386 (>= 5.5)
                         Breaks: libmysqlclient20 (!= 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The whole error message and command is here:

```
sudo apt-get --yes purge mysql-apt-config mysql-common mysql-
community-server mysql-workbench-community mysql-client mysql-community-client mysql-server mythes-en-us 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient20 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04)
                    Breaks: libmysqlclient20:i386 (!= 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04) but 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
 libmysqlclient20:i386 : Depends: mysql-common:i386 (>= 5.5)
                         Breaks: libmysqlclient20 (!= 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This error is particularly burdensome becaused dpkg has been acting up because of it, as well as apt-get. I am completely willing to get rid of MySQL if it means that I can get this error fixed.

Does anyone have advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Fix the dependencies with `sudo apt-get install -f` then try to remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue as you. For me the solution was to remove package using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libmysqlclient20:i386
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libqt4-sql-mysql
```

Hope it helps you...